# How to use third party api in symfony2

Tags: symfony

basically I am trying to integrate the thrid party api in symfony2 application. I have the php class from api documention. I want integrate that in my custom bundle controller.

I also looking to add the option to configure the api key and secrets. I don't know how to start. Please look at below that i want to do

Example:-

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

class DemoController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

    $myApi = new MyApi($key,$secret); // this is the stuff, I am trying to do!

        return array();
    }
}
```

First I try to create the [library format symfony package](https://github.com/RootaccezLabs/ODeskAPI). I don't know how to achive this this type. Can Some one tell me what are thinks I need to do.

Comment: Hey! may I know how you implemented this please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TO do this in a proper way, you have to declare you api class as a service & use dependancy injection to inject your parameters :

```
parameters:
    your_api.class:      Acme\HelloBundle\Lib\YourApiClass
    your_api.key:        "key value for your api"
    your_api.token:      "token value for your api"

services:
   yourApiService:
       class:        "%your_api.class%"
       arguments:    ["%your_api.key%", "%your_api.token%"]
```

And in your controller & many other places you'll have access like that :

`$api = $this->get('yourApiService');`

Take a look for more informations : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: thanks for reply. did you checked this [repo](https://github.com/RootaccezLabs/ODeskAPI). It's not a normal bundle. So I am not getting how to declare the services. how I need to alter the package, can you add some more notes

Comment: You can include this repo with your composer.json file by adding this line : rootaccez/odeskapi to requirements. After run a composer update & declare the api class as a service. Composer is the packager manager used by symfony ;) http://getcomposer.org/

Comment: Fabien, I think your not getting. I created that package. I know how to install. Where can I add the service in that package. I think this service noramlly come in example:-AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/services.yml right. How can i add that in that package

Comment: If your package is not a bundle, you can't declare your lib a service. The application which include this package have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it as a service:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html
when i try to implement an extern api, i think about adapter pattern:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: can you elaborate if you can. I have some understand with services. But did you checked the repo that i linked in question. Do you i need to create the bundle.

Comment: Whitout create the bundle you can use it. A service is a simple object  who you can find any where in you applivatoom

Comment: By using dependency injection